# Python signed multiplication is not commutative near floor division?

Tags: python, multiplication, signed

```
-1 * abs(-123)//10
```

is

```
-13
```

but

```
abs(-123)//10 * -1
```

is

```
-12
```

Why is this? What's the rule to be consistent and predictable when coding this?

Answer (score 2):

`//` is the floored division operator in Python. Since it's not standard division, the order matters.

```py
-1 * abs(-123)//10
```

becomes

```py
floor(((-1) * abs(-123)) / 10)
floor((-1 * 123) / 10)
floor(-123 / 10)
floor(-12.3)
-13
```

and

```py
abs(-123)//10 * -1
```

becomes

```py
floor(abs(-123) / 10) * (-1)
floor(123 / 10) * -1
floor(12.3) * -1
12 * -1
-12
```

as you can see, these become completely different expressions because in one of them, the negation happens before the `floor`ing, while the second has the negation happen afterwards. The `floor` function always rounds down (except when it's already an integer), and -13 is more "down" than -12.

There's a similar function called `trunc` (short for truncate) which will get rid of the decimal point, effectively rounding down for positive numbers and rounding up for negative numbers.

```py
import math
math.trunc(-1 * abs(-123) / 10)
```

and

```py
import math
math.trunc(abs(-123) / 10) * -1
```

Both of these become `-12`

```py
import math
math.trunc(-1 * abs(-123) / 10)
math.trunc(-1 * 123 / 10)
math.trunc(-123 / 10)
math.trunc(-12.3)
-12
```

```py
import math
math.trunc(abs(-123) / 10) * -1
math.trunc(123 / 10) * -1
math.trunc(12.3) * -1
12 * -1
-12
```

Answer (score 2):

The key facts are:

1. Integer division always rounds down - with "down" meaning "less positive" or "more negative". In the words of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=integer%20division#numeric-types-int-float-complex), rounding is "towards minus infinity" (not 'towards zero')
2. The `*` and `//` operators have [equal precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operator%20precedence#operator-precedence). So where both are used, the order is left-to-right.

So:

`-1 * abs(-123)//10` = `-1 * 123 // 10` = `(-1 * 123) // 10` = `-123 // 10` = `-13` (i.e. -12.3, rounded towards minus infinity)

and

`abs(-123)//10 * -1` = `123 // 10 * -1` = `(123 // 10) * -1` = `12 * -1` (rounding 12.3 towards minus infinity) = `-12`

Answer (score 1):

Because the first operation does `-1 * abs(-123)` then does integer division. Integer division always rounds towards `-Inf` and not zero. so the first one is actually `-123//10 = -13` and the second is `-(123//10) = -(12) = -12`

Answer (score 1):

An important rule about math I learnt, that when it comes to division and multiplication, You have to do them from left to right (as they teach at schools), or You can easily mess up. **No matter how attractive and tempting it looks.**
The order of operations matters.

### Operation 1

-1 * abs(-123) // 10

can be simplified to:

-1 * 123 // 10

-123 // 10

floor(-123 / 10)

floor(-12.3)`

Floor goes 'downwards', so:

`floor(-12.3)`

**-13**

### Operation 2.

abs(-123) // 10 * -1

can be simplified to:

`123 // 10 * -1

floor(123 / 10) * -1

Floor goes 'downwards' again, so:

floor(12.3) * -1

12 * -1

**-12**

#### Only addition and multiplication are commutative. Division and substraction aren't.